# SQL:StmtStarting event originated from application

Tags: sql-server, profiler

What does an `SQL:StmtStarting` event originated from application mean? Does it mean a raw SQL statement executed directly from the application?

For example, in the case of an `SP:StmtStarting`, it means that the current statement is inside an stored procedure, and thus not directly executed by the application, but by the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is an ad hoc SQL statement that is not part of a module. It could be sent on its own or it could be part of a batch.

Though I'm not sure why you're using Profiler; it is notoriously horrendous for performance. Just take a look at what [Joe Sack observed regarding the impact Profiler has on throughput](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/07/sql-trace/observer-overhead-and-waits) and [similar observations by Jonathan Kehayias](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/sql-trace/observer-overhead-trace-extended-events).

Or what value you gain from collecting the `Starting` events. The `Completed` events tell you much more about what happened (including things like duration).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take your suggestion. I'm a noob with SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: @guillegr123 use Profiler to configure a [server-side trace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293613.aspx), but never use Profiler to actually run it. And if you are on SQL Server 2008+, start learning [Extended Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630282.aspx).